# Removing unnecessary ZWNJ

Tags: php, regex, unicode

I want to remove unnecessary ZWNJ using RegEx, currently I hardcodeed some character that do not need ZWNJ in any situation, but how can I extend it to all such characters?

```
 preg_replace('#(?<=[ادذرزژوآأإءa-zA-Z])\x{u200C}#u', '', $parsi);
```

> When ZWNJ placed between two characters that would otherwise be
>   connected into a ligature, a ZWNJ causes them to be printed in their
>   final and initial forms, respectively. This is also an effect of a
>   space character, but a ZWNJ is used when it is desirable to keep the
>   words closer together.

If we need to limit the question to Arabic script is there any RegEx meta character to represent letters that do not have a medial form (and so forth do not need a succeeding ZWNJ )?

Comment: Seriously, we don't need a tag for every single control character. Please don't put the tag back in.

Comment: You are wrong about [a-zA-Z] not needing ZWNJ in any situation. In German, ligatures do not form across the joining boundaries of compound nouns. As an example, consider the German word "Schifffahrt" (made from "Schiff" + "fahrt", meaning "boat trip"). For correct typography you would need a ZWNJ to prevent the "fff" ligature from forming. More examples: "Auflage" ("Auf" + "lage"), "Brotzeit" ("Brot" + "zeit").

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes So can you please say which Latin letters belongs to the RegEx?

Answer (score -1):

As a non-Arab speaker, this is hardly my area of expertise, but...
[Here](http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/arabic.html) I found some information on Arabic unicode characters.

I would suggest doing something along the lines of:

```
 [\u0600-\u065F\u066A-\u06EF\u06FA-\u06FF]
```

To select all Arabic letters.

Comment: The ZWNJ is not an Arabic character. The rest of the pattern is a red herring.

Comment: What BoltClock said, plus a better regex would be: `\p{Script=Arab}`.

Comment: PSPst was asking for "all characters that do not need ZWNJ in any situation". I am simply suggesting that the hardcodeed values: [ادذرزژوآأإء] are replaced with something along the lines of [\u0600-\u065F\u066A-\u06EF\u06FA-\u06FF]